# How can some code bring input focus into a metro application?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

So from outside a metro application i want to write another app (or actually a script , in powershell trigger by a hotkey) that will put input focus on a metro APP.
For regular apps, i can find the process then get the MainWindowHandle and go from there, but for Metro apps, i can't the main window handle is always zero.

What i am trying to do is pretty basic. I have onenoteMX "pinned" or "snapped" to the side on my second monitor, and i'm going about my business, looking at it from time to time to see what i should do next, but when i want to edit it, i have to either alt-tab through all my apps of click it, because i can't bring it to focus

but the concept goes deeper than just my use case, like automated UI testing of metro apps etc.

Comment: I don't know this for certain, but I'm pretty sure you simply can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this.  Metro apps, or Win RT apps, don't have these abilities, and are completely sandboxed from one another.  There are several ways to find the other apps you have open, however.

1) Using a touch interface, swipe in from the left side of the screen, and then quickly swipe back out.  It will bring up a vertical list of all of the apps you currently have option.

2)  Using a mouse, move your mouse to the upper- or lower-left corner, and then move up (or down) to the middle of the screen.  The same list of apps will appear.

3)  Finally, if you drag in from the left side of the screen, it should always bring back the last app you were running.  Much like Alt-Tab.